# What is eclipse's .classpath output?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I was looking in my project's .classpath file, and I noticed an interesting line:

```
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
```

When I saw it, I was wondering, what does it do, and when would you want to change it?
I looked for quite a while online and in the eclipse documentation for about a day, but I can't find any mentions of it (I found it in other people's classpath files, but those posts addressed other things).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiled .class files from Eclipse by default go into bin sub-folder of your project.
So ... Eclipse is including those compiled .class files in your project's classpath.
Seems quite normal to me.

For more details you may Google "eclipse classpath file" or "eclipse .classpath file".

Answer (score 0):

This is where to configuration for the output folder is stored. This corresponds to the `Default output folder` value on the Java Build Path properties Source page:
[image: Java Build Path]